# Why is jupyter notebook throwing an IndentationError?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have some really strange behaviour using `jupyter notebook`.

Here's a basic python function:

```
def configure_wg_drem(data_file_pattern): return data_file_pattern

configure_wg_drem('Adult/Adult_*.txt')
```

which gives me:

```
'Adult/Adult_*.txt'
```

But the same function with normal python formatting:

```
def configure_wg_drem(data_file_pattern): 
    return data_file_pattern

configure_wg_drem('Adult/Adult_*.txt')
```

Throws an error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-97-c97da191fc79>", line 29
    return data_file_pattern
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this?

I've tried using the automatic indentation that jupyter notebook gives when you use a colon and press enter, a single tab as well as four spaces instead of a tab. All with the same results.

I've also tried restarting `jupyter notebook` and get the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you certain there is no non-printable character somewhere in between? Create a new cell, write out `def foo(bar):\nreturn bar`, try it and morph it until it looks like your original example.

Answer (score 2):

You may have mixed TAB and spaces in your code.

I recommend you using spaces only.